# My array isn't taking any data in it, only one and that's it, and I don't understand why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I'm trying to add "livres" into my array "li", everytime I check for the lenght of "li", it always shows 1, even when I enter more than one, I'm calling this function in a button in my index.html. I can't continue my work because of this, I've shown my teacher the problem and she doesn't have a solution for me... I don't know what to do! Here's the code:

```
var li = new Array();
function enregistrer()
{
    var code = Number(document.getElementById('code1').value);
    var titre = String(document.getElementById('titre1').value);
    var auteur = String(document.getElementById('auteur1').value);
    var l = new livre(code, titre, auteur);
    li.push(l);
    alert(li.length);
}
```

Comment: what is ```livre``` is it a custom class you are instantiating?

Comment: Probably your button is in a form, and the form submits when you click it, and so the page reloads.

Comment: @HadiPawar It's a constructor for creating "Livres" object

Comment: @trincot How do I fix this problem? removing my button from the form?

Comment: Remove the form tag only. Or deal with cancelling the default event, by calling `event.preventDefault();`, but your click handler should then take the `event` argument. Note that your question does not include the necessary information, but on the other hand there are lots of similar questions that come down to this problem.

Comment: @trincot That worked! Thanks a lot seriously

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a form to insert data into the array.
When you put any button in a form, it will act as a submit button for that form, this means the page will reload, if you haven't put an `action="external file"` as an attribute to the form.

Other than that, I've rewritten your code to make it easier to debug, and I have also created an alias of the 'livres' object.

```
function livre(a, b, c){
    this.val1 = a;
    this.val2 = b;
    this.val3 = c;
}
var li = new Array();
function enregistrer()
{
    var code = Number(3);
    var titre = String('thishere');
    var auteur = String('another');
    var l = new livre(code, titre, auteur);
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        li.push(l);
    }
    console.log(li.length);
}
enregistrer();
```

When you call this function, it will add `l` which is just `1` instance of the `livres` object to the array `li` ... and the output is "1"